# how to subscribe a user to a Mailchimp list using Gibbon on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm trying to subscribe users to a mailchimp, not sure if i'm making an error on the form or the controller , I followed some tutorials online but haven't had no luck.

I'll appreciated any help
thank you

Here is my view using a form_tag

```
<h1>Newsletter subscribe</h1>
<p>Sign up for email  updates</p>
<%= form_tag('subscribenow', method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote: "true") do %>
   <%= email_field(:email,:address, {id: "email", placeholder: "email address"}) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Sign me up!") %>
<% end %>
```

this  is my controller

```
class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
def index
end

 def subscribe

    list_id = "my_id"
    gb = Gibbon::API.new

    gb.lists.subscribe({:id => list_id,
                        :email => {:email => 'email_address'}, 
                        :merge_vars => {:FNAME => 'First Name', 
                        :LNAME => 'Last Name'},             
                        :double_option => false})
 end
end
```

(these are my routes on the routes.rb file)

```
get 'emailsignup'  => 'emailapi#index'
post 'subscribenow'=> 'emailapi#subscribe'
```

my initializer file

```
  Gibbon::API.api_key = "my_api_key"
  Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
  Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

This is the error I get on my local server

```
Started POST "/subscribenow" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-12 07:49:10 -0800
```

ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by EmailapiController#subscribe as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>{"address"=>"example@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Sign me up!"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 353ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template emailapi/subscribe, application/subscribe with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/blanco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/blanco/Desktop/Rails_projects/dansbuzz/app/views"
  * "/Users/blanco/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
):

Comment: Some information about your error would help. You're also suppressing the error Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false which makes it harder to find your error!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback,I've added the errors I get in my local server

Comment: The error is telling you the problem -- and its not mailchimp. Rails is going to automatically render the emailapi/subscribe.html.erb template unless you do something like redirect with a flash message or render :ok